# How to use RxJS in Angular2 to interact with HATEOAS API?

Tags: rxjs, angular2-services, hateoas

I have a (Django) API that implements HATEOAS, so typically foreign keyed objects come through as URLs to other API endpoints. The following is the result from `http://localhost:8000/brew-monitor/api/fermentations/1/` and is a Fermentation object with associated Dataset objects:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "My Beer",
    "datasets": [
        "http://localhost:8000/brew-monitor/api/datasets/1/",
        "http://localhost:8000/brew-monitor/api/datasets/2/"
    ]
}
```

I need to write a service that will GET the above object and then iterate through the `datasets` URLs and GET those as well (I know, maybe it can be more efficient but I'm teaching myself about HATEOAS).

A Dataset object looks like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "unit": "DEGF",
    "variable_measured": "T",
    "fermentation": "http://localhost:8000/brew-monitor/api/fermentations/1/",
    "logging_device": "http://localhost:8000/brew-monitor/api/devices/1/",
    "controls": [],
    "active": true,
    "datapoints": [
        "http://localhost:8000/brew-monitor/api/datapoints/1/",
        "http://localhost:8000/brew-monitor/api/datapoints/2/",
        "http://localhost:8000/brew-monitor/api/datapoints/3/"
    ]
}
```

So I want the final result from my service to look like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "My Beer",
    "datasets": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "unit": "DEGF",
            "variable_measured": "T",
            "fermentation": "http://localhost:8000/brew-monitor/api/fermentations/1/",
            "logging_device": "http://localhost:8000/brew-monitor/api/devices/1/",
            "controls": [],
            "active": true,
            "datapoints": [
                "http://localhost:8000/brew-monitor/api/datapoints/1/",
                "http://localhost:8000/brew-monitor/api/datapoints/2/",
                "http://localhost:8000/brew-monitor/api/datapoints/3/"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "unit": "UNITLESS",
            "variable_measured": "SG",
            "fermentation": "http://localhost:8000/brew-monitor/api/fermentations/1/",
            "logging_device": "http://localhost:8000/brew-monitor/api/devices/1/",
            "controls": [],
            "active": true,
            "datapoints": [
                "http://localhost:8000/brew-monitor/api/datapoints/4/",
                "http://localhost:8000/brew-monitor/api/datapoints/5/",
                "http://localhost:8000/brew-monitor/api/datapoints/6/"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I just *know* RxJS can do this. How?

*EDIT:* I have a solution that uses nested subscriptions but I think it's common knowledge that you should avoid that. So no nested subscriptions please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do something like this

```
const source$ = of({
    "id": 1,
    "name": "My Beer",
    "datasets": [
        "http://localhost:8000/brew-monitor/api/datasets/1/",
        "http://localhost:8000/brew-monitor/api/datasets/2/"
    ]
});
const data$ = source$.pipe(
  switchMap(source => this.getDatasets(source))
);

data$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

function getDatasets(source) {
  return forkJoin(source.datasets.map(endpoint => fakeHttpRequest(endpoint))).pipe(
    map(results => ({...source, datasets: results}))
  );
}

function fakeHttpRequest(endpoint) {
  return of({
    test: '123'
  });
}
```

RXJS is awesome.

Comment: This worked great! I was even able to add a second layer of nesting api calls, not that it's necessarily advisable to do this in practice. I have mixed feeling about HATEOAS.